# Use DOSBox's SB16 Emulation in real DOS?

Tags: audio, sound-card, ms-dos, emulation, midi

So I've been thinking, is it potentially possible to use DOSBox's sound emulation software in real DOS on machines with AC97/IHDA chips so that you can use audio properly? I've been using the PC Speaker for sound effects, and I love the general feel of the *bleep* *bloop* *waaaamp* sound effects, I've even been using MIDIPlayer to listen to MIDI versions of game soundtracks when I'm not actively playing them, however there is one giant caveat: many DOS games can only play FX through the PC Speaker and not music. I've searched far and wide to find a solution to this, and I finally thought "I may not have a SB, or an AdLib, or a Covox... but could I emulate them?".

And that is the question of the day: would it be possible to compile and run DOSBox's SB/AdLib/GeneralMIDI emulators and run them on actual DOS that I can keep my 8 bit MIDI sound effects but use a virtual SB for piping the music to my AC97/IHDA? (And no, switching to DOSBox or a VM is not an option, I like to keep things authentic, and would sooner just buy a sound card than do that, so please don't suggest it.)

Alternatively would it be possible to build/run DOSBox inside of DOS as to get the hardware-emu environment without having to use DOSBox exclusively? Say by launching DOSBox with game specific configs through the DOS prompt?

Answer (score 3):

DOS programs expect to access the hardware directly.

Emulating such direct hardware accesses would require some kind of virtualization (DOSBox or a VM), or that the actual hardware has built-in support for emulation (modern chipsets typically can do this to allow to redirect PS/2 keyboard/mouse accesses to USB, but not for anything else).

Comment: would it theoretically be possible to set up a system in actual DOS which launches DOSBox, and then the game of choice in DOSBox directly so that sound could be achieved through DOSBox's SB16 emulation that way? Say a batch file that launches DOSBox using *doom.cfg*, which contains the autoexec lines `CD GAMES\DOOM_SE\; DOS32A.exe DOOM.exe`? Or would sound still not be available due to the host (DOS's) lack of AC97/IHDA drivers all the same?

Comment: DOSBox expects a real OS with drivers for the actual hardware.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question, for example if I were running FreeDOS directly on the machine, perhaps with VirtualSoundBlaster or VIAUDIO.COM what would be preventing it from functioning at that point? (Aside from the possibility that DOSBox simply won't run in DOS at all).

Comment: There are some FreeDos extenders that mention Realtek ac97/modern hardware, but they all seem to be virtualized. DOS has protected mode, which is not exactly bare metal, but I think what you are more appropriately asking is for a "driver wrapper" rather than an emulator. The bigger issue here is that DOS software that is naive of modern hardware is going to have problems with speed etc. DosBox resolves this by enabling a throttle, but a very many e.g. old games ran on a tight loop without a timer.

Comment: @AlisonE.E.: You'd still have to rewrite DOSBox to run on actual DOS, which means you'd have to rewrite SDL to run on actual DOS. While possible in principle, not a trivial task.

Comment: @dirkt As I figured unfortunately. Well, thanks for the info, its good to at least have confirmation. BTW on a somewhat related note, would it be possible to create a boot floppy for DOS that boots to a local HDD install? (I already have macOS, Windows, and RemixOS installed, and installing the boot data for DOS with the most recent stable FreeDOS installer would cause me to lose access to at least two of these at any given time based on the way I have my partitioning/boot records set up.)

Answer (score 2):

There are some software emulators for SB (and other sound cards) for DOS like VSB (Virtual Sound Blaster), TEMU (Tandy sound chip emulator) and remus.

http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=9524

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, I had tried VSB before, but its fairly obscure and the only version I could find was quite old and had serious incompatibilities with the version of DOS I'm using, as well as lacking support for AC97/IHDA chips. I did not realize however that there were other such programmes available for other sound cards. I will have to look into these.